# Python AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, web-scraping, attributes

I want to crawl a website.

However, an error occurred.

```
C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/scrap.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/scrap.py", line 10, in <module>
    driver.get('https://www.powderroom.co.kr/rankings/c1100')
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Process finished with exit code 1

How do I resolve this error?

Thank you for your advice.

```
#py3.6,pycharm
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS=("c:|phantomjs-2.1.1/windows/bin/phantomjs")

driver.get('https://www.powderroom.co.kr/rankings/c1100')
i = 0
while i < 8:
    i = i + 1
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(1)

bs = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')

titles = bs.findAll('div', attrs={'class':'fs-5 tc-gray-1'})
for title in titles:
    result = str(title.find_all(text=True))
    result = re.sub('[\{\}\[\]\/?.,;:|\)*~`!^\-_+<>@\#$%&\\\=\(\'\"]', '', result)
    print(result)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: I don't think the error could've been any clearer on why the program wasn't working.

Comment: print `driver` then you will understand

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you have a typo:

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS=("c:|phantomjs-2.1.1/windows/bin/phantomjs")
                            ^
```

I don't think that equals sign is supposed to be there.

Answer (score 0):

Did A test with fresh anaconda env. 
I got the same error until I installed phantomjs. Up until that point it looks like python just things driver is a string variable, not something special that has a get method.

if you're not using anaconda here is a like to phantoms page
http://phantomjs.org/download.html

if your using anaconda just follow the instructions here
https://anaconda.org/trent/phantomjs

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Brionius made agreat observation. I didn't notice the second equal sign